# Is this pipe layout acceptable?

Tags: heating, air-conditioning

We recently had our heater and air conditioner replaced, and now the drainage pipe is installed on the floor of the basement. It's quite annoying and it wasn't like that before (it was on the walls near the ceiling).

Is this layout acceptable (standard practice), or should we ask for it to be re-done?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like a tripping hazard to me.

Comment: It's probably not the best design, but at least it goes to a drain. I find it amusing that they anchored it to the floor. Not sure what the support requirements are for pipe on the floor, but at least they tried. Unless there's a slope to the floor, it's not likely this meets slope requirements.

Comment: @Tester101 There's a very gradual slope to the drain. Probably < 1°.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's certainly not pretty. But going to a floor drain rarely is, unless the drain happens to be positioned remarkably conveniently.

An alternative would be to drain into a small container with a pump, whose output could be routed as needed. That's what was done in my house. This does require providing power to the pump, of course, but since I have a condensing boiler it actually has an outlet for that pump built into it.

Comment: Hmm. I think before the pipe went to a laundry sink...but the AC was in a different place.

Comment: Mine runs into the washing-machine drain, which is on the far side of the basement. The **condensate pump** makes that possible. (Searching for that term will find a number of models.)